# Get IntelliJ "DejaVu Sans Mono" font on Windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, settings

At work, I use IntelliJ on Linux Mint and I set the `DejaVu Sans Mono` font. At home, I use Windows10 but I can't see this font on the font setting panel. Is there a way to add it because those proposed by defaut are really useless. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not have the fonts, you can download and install from this link: [DejaVu Fonts on GitHub](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/Download.html)

I installed only `DejaVu Sans Mono` from the provided zip file and restarted "IntelliJ IDEA". Then, goto `File > Settings > Editor > Font` and uncheck the first checkbox `Show only monospaced fonts` and then select the font you want, `DejaVu Sans Mono` in your case.

Screenshot: [image]

Finally, the editor looks like this:

[image]

And, for changing font of other parts of the IDE, goto `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance` and deselect "Override default fonts` and choose your preferred font.

Screenshot:

[image]

---

---

---

**EDIT: How to Install Font: ** Installing Font (Easy Way): You open the zip file after downloading, then go into `dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37\ttf` directory, you will find the font named `DejaVuSansMono.ttf`.

[image]

Double click on the font and you will have the following window. You then have to click on `Install` to install it on the system. I believe you need proper permission into the system to install it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these details, where do you install the downloaded font?

Comment: @ImtiazeA, I have installed DejaVuSansMono, but it doesn't appear in the list of the fonts, even after I uncheck the checkbox. Any ideas of what can be wrong? Thanks ahead.

Comment: @Alex - Not sure, try restarting your machine and see if it works, also make sure you are on correct font settings page.

Comment: Restarting didn't help. Still no Dejavu font in the list